# Is there a pattern for this?

Tags: design-patterns

i have something that requires a matrix of values, similar to pokemon:

[image: pokemon]
<sub>(source: [firechao.com](http://firechao.com/Images/PokemonGuide/PokemonTypeChart.PNG))</sub>

i have a class object for each of the types, is there a pattern or a good way to implement this, as a middle layer or in the classes?

Comment: can you make it not so brightly, please?

Comment: Do they actually need to be classes? Can you use enumerated types? I don't have enough information to be sure I'm giving you a good answer. Could you please explain a little more what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Roman: Reduce the brightness of your monitor!

Comment: What does a color mean? Especially 'violet' which is 0. What's the difference between violet and white in the domain?

Comment: @Roman: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Elemental_types

Comment: @Roman: I guess no color means: x1

Comment: @Roman: White = &times; 1 = No change. The color indicates the effectiveness of an attack. *And that's not the focus of this question.*

Comment: the values don't matter, was hoping for something other than a hardcoded matrix

Comment: If the values really don't matter, a 2D matrix may work best. But if you have 90% of the matrix filled with '1's, a sparse-matrix solution (for example, a map with a combined key (attacker,defender) will work better. And it makes a difference if the information shall be hardcoded into your program, or if the user shall be able to extend the matrix at running time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, give a try to the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) design pattern.

**hint**: just create a `Normal` class with all the stats you need. Then create a `Decorator` class for each 
row of the matrix: `FireDecorator`, `SteelDecorator`, that apply the multiplier for attack/defense.

**bonus #1**: you can build very easily a "Fire Steel Character", dynamically (the intent of the pattern)

**bonus #2**: when you add another character, say the "Giant", you just add *one* class, 
without touching anything else

Comment: -1, this is a perfect example of how to over-pattern something.

Comment: @Doc it depends on how he wants to use this table. If it's just a table, yes, overkill. If not, the above is a legit answer.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that even if the OP wants more than a table, this solution is overkill. And to add a 'Giant', one has to add two classes: a Giant and a GiantDecorator, so the bonus #2 is wrong.

Comment: @Doc: no, you only need a `GiantDecorator` since you need to modify only the attack/defense bonuses (same as for `Rock`, `Bug`, etc).

Answer (score 7):

Why make it so complicated - For the sake of maintenance make it like it looks.
A two dimensional array will do fine and since it is static will give you best lookup performance - You then just need a way to go from Name/Type to array index.

Comment: thanks, i omit the array solution, but didnt know if there was a better design out there

Answer (score 3):

It's a basic multiple-dispatch problem. Unfortunately, most languages do not support multiple dispatch.

So I would probably use a map of maps.  The outer map maps attacks to maps of defenses, which in turn map defenses to scores/effects/whatever.

You could use the Visitor pattern, but that gets cumbersome fast.

In Python, assuming that you aren't using much subclassing (e.g. no subclasses of Ice), you could use a dictionary mapping `(attack,defense)` tuples to scores.  That would be a rather clean solution and would be supported by a variety of languages (all you need is a Pair class and an ability to represent attack types as objects, either via a class object or something like an enum).

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary uses the names of the attacker (Fire, Ice etc) as key that contains dictionaries which use the names of the defender as keys and the multiplers as values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 maps (map in java, in other languages it can have another name): 1 for

`Attacking-->Defending` and one for `Defending-->Attacking`.

Let's consider Attacking-->Defending example. Map will contain Attacking types as keys and arrays of Defending types as values. For example:

Fire-->[Fire, Water, Grass, Ice, Bug, Rock, Dragon, Steel]

Comment: I edited a minor misspelling, unless you really did mean *defenting* than I apologize. :(

Comment: @Anthony I can't edit your comment, but I think you meant "then".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate class for each "thing" that these types qualify (your pokemon or whatever) the classes could hold a static hash / map / dictionary structure that gives what multipliers there are for attacking the others. Such a hash would represent one row of the table. If you really need the reverse lookup, just make one more that stores the column of information.

Answer (score 0):

A Mediator pattern could do the trick. It is more a middle layer solution than an in-class solution.

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx

- In the above example, `Colleague` will be your `Type`.
- `ConcreteColleague0` will be `Normal`, `ConcreteColleague1` will be `Fire`, `ConcreteColleague2` will be `Water`, `ConcreteColleague3` will be  `Grass`...
- `Mediator` will provides an interface with method `setAttacker(Type attacker)`, `setDefender(Type defender)` and `fight()`. They will **all** be implemented in the `ConcreteMediator`. It means class attribute defender and attacker should be in the `ConcreteMediator`
- `ConcreteMediator` will hide the implementation of your matrix. It can be a map of map - dictionary of dictionary for some languages -. I may also be a single map where the key is made of the concatenation of the attacker and defender types like `factor["fire_fire"] = 0.5, factor["fire_water"] = 0.5, factor["water_fire"] = 2`, etc. If association doesn't exist in the matrix, then it gets default factor 1. In addition to getting the damage factor, it may apply damage.

IMO advantages are:

1. If you add a new Type, then it will gets the default damage factor. So, adding a new Type doesn't involve development , except if the default one is not enough.
2. You `ConcreteMediator` can do much more than get a damage factor, it can apply it and so on.
3. You could develop other `ConcreteMediator` - i.e. relationships - than fight between attacker and defender. For instance `steal()`, `observe()`, etc. If you add other setters to the mediator, the scope of relationships will be wider.